# Mysql/laravel Sort values of dynamic table

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel

I have 3 tables

Table User

| id | first_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | abc |
| 2 | xyz |

Table UserCustomData

| id | user_id | field_id | value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 4545. |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 12121 |

Table fields

| id | name | type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | phone | text |
| 2 | address | select |

Fields are dynamic so there can be any number of fields this way I should be able to sort the rows

What I want

| id | user_id | first_name | phone | address |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | abc | 4545 | . |
| 2 | 1 | xyz | 12121 | . |

ex. Sortby phone asc OR SORTBY firstName etc

I am using laravel so laravel aproach can also work but will be nice if I get it worked the core way.

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: Did you try anything ? Can you try anything ?

Comment: Ofcourse I have!!!

I tried the join but then coz I am making rows in to column groupby will not work.

Also 

`User::join('user_field_data', function($query) {
    return $query->on('users.id', 'user_field_data.user_id')->where('field_id', 12);
})->orderBy('user_field_data.value')->get();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to figure out the query that can do the magic it is

Below query will create 2 sql

```
array:2 [▼
```

0 => array:3 [▼
"query" => "select * from `users` left join `user_field_data` on `users`.`id` = `user_field_data`.`user_id` and `user_field_data`.`field_id` = ? where `deleted` = ? order by `user_field_data`.`value` asc ◀"
"bindings" => array:2 [▼
0 => 23
1 => 0
]
"time" => 0.7
]
1 => array:3 [▼
"query" => "select `user_field_data`.*, `fields`.`label`, `fields`.`name`, `field_values`.`value` as `field_value` from `user_field_data` left join `fields` on `fields`.`id` = `user_field_data`.`field_id` left join `field_values` on `field_values`.`id` = `user_field_data`.`field_value_id` where `user_field_data`.`user_id` in (0, 354, 439, 457, 461, 465, 469, 491, 495) ◀"
"bindings" => []
"time" => 0.32
]
]

```
       $m = $this->_query
             ->select('users.*')
             ->leftjoin('user_field_data', function($query) {
            return $query->on('users.id', 'user_field_data.user_id')->where('user_field_data.field_id', 23);
            })->orderBy('user_field_data.value', $direction)->get();
```